# Odd behavior when clicking on TextArea after page load

Tags: html, css

I do experience an odd behavior with a text area. The everytime page is loaded and I click on the text area the below happens, and it only happens once (until next page refresh or load). If the page is NOT refreshed for example this will not happen for 2nd time.

[image]

Page originally looks like that.

[image]

```css
.filter-text-area {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 437px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <form id="dates" method="GET" action="<?php echo site_url('weq4u/runFilter/') ?>">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <textarea class="filter-text-area" name="data" id="data"></textarea>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am not entirely sure what could cause this...

Comment: Your textarea is not wrapped in a cell (<td></td>)

Comment: @BobMeijwaard good spot - forgot that, but this isn't actually the cause of the issue here

Comment: Was afraid of that, have you tried replacing the custom CSS with (bootstrap) class "form-control" and see the difference in behaviour?

Comment: @BobMeijwaard i tried, although the panel header no longer disappears and the text box does not shift, it still flashes when its clicked for the 1st time.

Comment: It might be possible that is some other css or maybe even some javascript that is responding with the piece of code you pasted. It is pretty hard to say, without knowing what other code you are running next to this.

Comment: @BobMeijwaard i have commented out all the other css/js link so i was left only with the text-area and original bootstrap.css and it was still happening. I wonder if this could be related to the codeigniter framework somehow...

Comment: Hmm, i have no experience with codeigniter, perhaps you could isolate the issue further and create a clean HTML file, and in steps add the required css/js to see at what point this behavior starts to show up.